# Firefox forwards me to another website instead of passing data while Drag&Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have a strange problem.. I have to pass data while Drag&Drop. I use jQuery therefore I do it via `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData` and `setData`.

It's working fine in Chrome and Opera, but in Firefox it's forwarding me to another website, regarding on the content I pass. This example forwards me to **hello.com** because of the *"hello"* in *setData*.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drop")
    .on("drop", function(event) {
      console.log("drop");
      msg = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      console.log(msg);
    })
    .on("dragover", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

  $("#drag")
    .on("dragstart", function(event) {
      event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", "hello");
    });
});
```

Try it here (move the red square on the black): https://jsfiddle.net/opfzqc7g/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember a `preventDefault()` was used in the drop event as well, I don't know why it works in other browsers though.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drop")
    .on("drop", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("drop");
      msg = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      console.log(msg);
    })
    .on("dragover", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

  $("#drag")
    .on("dragstart", function(event) {
      event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", "hello");
    });
});
```